# Xdebug not working on PhpStorm - PHP 7.2.10, Ubuntu 18.04.01

Tags: php, apache, phpstorm, xdebug, ubuntu-18.04

I was using Ubuntu 17.10 and everything worked. However, after a update to Ubuntu version 18.04 along with a clean install I can no longer get my Xdebug to work properly.

I tried to implement solutions that I found at SO or other sites but none of them helped.

**php -v**

```
PHP 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Sep 13 2018 13:45:02) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

Here is my configuration in php.ini

**/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini**

(same with /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini file)

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension ="/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so"
xdebug.profiler_enable =On
xdebug.auto_trace=On
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=90000
```

**Xdebug Chrome extension - ide key option**

(I cleaned previous cookie belongs to Eclipse)

```
PHPSTORM
```

some lines of `phpinfo();`

```
PHP Version:   7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
Loaded Configuration File:  /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
Additional .ini files parsed: /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
--xdebug--
Version:    2.6.0
IDE Key:    1
xdebug.remote_enable:   On
```

What is wrong with my setup? And what can I do to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working".  You may want to spend more time describing the problem first.

Comment: @Devon that means nothing happens

Comment: That doesn't describe the problem.  What code are you running?  Where are you running it?  What debug config did you set up in phpstorm?  How are you setting the breakpoints?

Comment: @Devon I'm running a laravel framework v5.7, on phpstorm settings->lang&frameworks->php cli added, spcified additional xdebug path.. chrome xdebug extension installed, configured for phpstorm.  Also what do you mean with I set the breakpoints, I didin't get that question ?

Comment: I've never used the chrome xdebug extension, so I'm not sure what that does, but you would normally configure a `PHP Web Page` debug config, set your breakpoints, and then run that debug config all through PHPStorm.  You shouldn't need a chrome extension.

Comment: Read https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/creating-php-web-application-debug-configuration.html

Comment: I am a PhpStorm team member, and we actually don't recommend using Run configurations for web debug, it's cumbersome cause the URL needs to be edited manually each time, and you can't choose at what point you want to start the debugging session. Devon, I hope it doesn't sound rude, you surely can go whatever way you like.

@TeomanTıngır Usually, looking at the [Xdebug remote log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544819-How-to-collect-remote-log-for-XDebug) helps a lot when you don't understand what's happening with your debuggin session. Please set it up.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the server runs xdebug you can place xdebug_break(); inside your php code. This should "hard" pause your script after the call. If not, check your server config.

Answer (score 0):

Phpinfo() shows a value of 1 and not PHPSTORM as intended